# Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword select

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to overcome this? When I create a new table, I'm getting this error.

This is my query:

```
create table empnew 
as select * from emp;
```

And this is the error message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Don't deserve an upvote for an inability to look up basic syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You have a SQL Server error.  The correct syntax in that database is:

```
select e.*
into empnew
from emp e;
```